# Pygame window hang

Tags: python, pygame

im using pygame to do a plot (i know that i can use matplotlib but this suits better), the plot render correctly but the pygame window hangs, is something wrong with the code?

```
        xp,yp = 400,400
        pantalla = pygame.display.set_mode((xp,yp))
        pantalla.fill((255,255,255))
        for x in range(0,xp,20):
            pygame.draw.line(pantalla, (0,0,0) , (x, 1), (x, 800))
        for y in range(0,yp,20):
            pygame.draw.line(pantalla, (0,0,0) , (1, y), (800, y))
        pygame.draw.line(pantalla,(0,0,0), (yp/2,0),(yp/2,xp),4)
        pygame.draw.line(pantalla,(0,0,0), (0,xp/2),(yp,xp/2),4)
        pygame.draw.circle(pantalla, (0,0,0), (xp/2,yp/2),5)
        pygame.display.flip()
        #### La pantalla esta cargada totalmente a partir de aqui
        while 1:
            colora,colorb,colorc = random.randint(0,0),random.randint(0,0),random.randint(0,0)
            listacoordenadas = []
            for x in range(-6,7):
                listacoordenadas.append((x*20+xp/2,yp/2-eval(code)*20))
            for indice in range(len(listacoordenadas)-1):
                pygame.draw.line(pantalla,(colora,colorb,colorc), listacoordenadas[indice],listacoordenadas[indice+1],4)
            pygame.display.flip()
        raw_input()
```

Comment: `while 1:` and no explicit `break` - What do you expect to happen there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is simply that you have no way to leave the loop.  Put somewhere in your `while 1:` loop the following code.  Also, remember to `import sys`.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
```